# Swap children's depth

Tags: html5-canvas, createjs

I am using canvas and createjs. I have a container that has an eventListener attached to it so that any child in that container can be selected. When a child is selected I can drag it around on the stage but it is relative to its index so it is above some children and below others. I would like to move the above child to the top index. In flash I was able to swap the depth of that child and I was wondering if there is something similar in Javascript?

Thx.

Comment: it is the same as in flash http://createjs.com/Docs/EaselJS/classes/Container.html#method_swapChildren

Answer (score 0):

All you gotta do is:

```
yourContainer.addChild(selectedChild);
```

this will pull your object to the top of your display list.